# jCarouselLite plugin not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcarousellite

This problem is plaguing me. I've used jCarouselLite for years and years, I even added a "fade" feature to the original library released by Ganeshji Marwaha for my own use. I recently switched to [the new plug-in](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite) because it is still supported, it uses touch events, and it can be responsive. But I have had no luck in using it.

I am almost certainly doing something stupid, but I can not figure out what... Can anyone take a look with fresh eyes at this homepage implementation?

http://staging.tbc1927.com/www/

The implementation here is not responsive, but I would like swipe supported.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".homecarousel").jCarouselLite({
    visible: 1,
    auto: 12000,
    speed: 800, 
    responsive: false,
    swipe: true,
    circular: true,
    btnNext: ".next", 
    btnPrev: ".previous"
    });
});
```

The CSS is simple enough, and I am letting the plug in do the heavy lifting. The jQuery I am using is the same as they recommend (1.7.2), though I had been using a newer version as well with no luck (1.8).

When the carousel initially loads, the first slide is fine. Then it goes away, and the whole carousel is positioned WAY off the page. The longer the carousel runs, the more off the page it is positioned.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the plug in helped me out here. The plug in changed the "auto" option to a boolean value, and the "12000" value was throwing it off. To set the animation delay, the plug in now uses a parameter called "timeout". The correct implementation script should be:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".homecarousel").jCarouselLite({
    visible: 1,
    auto: true,
    timeout: 12000,
    speed: 800, 
    responsive: false,
    swipe: true,
    circular: true,
    btnNext: ".next", 
    btnPrev: ".previous"
    });
});
```